# facebook login implementation in joomla 3.0 site

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, joomla, facebook-php-sdk

I am implementing Facebook login into joomla login module. I tool code from Facebook sdk site and I am able to authenticate using facebook. After authentication I am getting user data also like username and email id.

Now, Problem is it is not logging-in into my joomla site using this information? I am using this information to create an user with random password.

If I can get any reference of any tutorial where facebook login is implemented. That will be really helpful.

Please let me know if you want any specific piece of code.

I don't want to go for any extension because I have few other changes also, in the same module.

Comment: I don't know why this question is downvoted? If you don't the answer or you can't help..please leave it alone here but don't downvote...and If have concern or issue...just tell me in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

That's not surprising considering the Facebook SDK is not concerned with interacting with other websites, especially since there are so many different website platforms.

I know it's not the answer you want, but I honestly think you're going to have to use a 3rd party extension. The good news is that there are plenty of them that will create a Facebook/website authentication plugin.

I suggest [starting here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension?searchall=&filter[tags][]=329&filter[core_catid]=&filter[includes]=&filter[versions]=&filter[type]=&filter[hasdemo]=&order=&filter[newupdated]=&filter[score]=&filter[favourites]=&dir=DESC&limitstart=0&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&Itemid=145&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1)

Comment: And if you want to code your own you could use JFacebook.

Comment: What is this jFacebook? Can you please provide a link?

Comment: @CreativeChris Can you please provide me some place where can i get some idea at least

Comment: Sure thing: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension?searchall=&filter[tags][]=329&filter[core_catid]=&filter[includes]=&filter[versions]=&filter[type]=&filter[hasdemo]=&order=&filter[newupdated]=&filter[score]=&filter[favourites]=&dir=DESC&limitstart=0&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&Itemid=145&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1